# post request array return

Tags: php, laravel

the post method return this array:

```
"aff":{
    "12621":"on",
    "9897":"on",
    "13022":"on",
    "3441":"on",
    "5994":"on"
}
```

I need to work with the only numbers of this array.
if i put this array in my update query i get this error:

```
update [table] set [arrived] = 1 where [CandidatureID] in (on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on))
```

As you can see I need to put the numbers id from the aff array in the query. Any suggest?

Comment: And where is the code you are using to create this query?

Comment: json_decode() ?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PHP `array_keys` method.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
whereIn('CandidatureID', array_keys($onArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keys of array. Use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for that:

```
$aff = json_decode($_POST['aff'], true); // {"12621":"on","9897":"on","13022":"on","3441":"on","5994":"on"}
$keys = array_keys($aff); // ["12621" => "on","9897" => "on","13022" => "on","3441" => "on","5994" => "on"]

var_dump($keys); // ["12621", "9897", "13022", "3441", "5994"]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can foreach the `$aff` and get its `key`

```
@foreach ($aff as $key => $data)
    <li>{{ $key }}: {{ $data }}</li>
@endforeach
```